Looking for a movie about brothers and saving a town
I'm having trouble trying to remember this movie. I watched it a few months ago on Netflix and can't find it anywhere. 
I remember it's about two brothers and a dad. One brother comes back from the military after his mom just died. The brothers aren't close because of the one brother leaving. Anyway, something happens to the town and the two brothers see their dad get shot. They gather some people up and one brother trains them all how to shoot and they try to kill some other people. Then one brother goes against the plan to get his girlfriend (who's in an orange jumpsuit on a school bus) and their friend gets shot because of it. They regroup again and kill the people. 
Sorry that's all I can remember and can't find it anywhere 
I don't remember any of the actors, so might be an independent movie. Not from later than the 2000's. 

I think Netflix shows you a list of movies you've watched recently...?

I believe you are looking for the movie, Red Dawn (2012). It is a remake of a movie of the same name that was released in 1984. 
Plot Summary of the Movie goes like this

When North Korean troops invade U.S. soil and take over the city of Spokane, Wash., a recently returned Iraq War veteran (Chris Hemsworth) and a group of teens (Josh Peck, Josh Hutcherson) flee to the woods and form a band of freedom fighters. Dubbing themselves the Wolverines, the youths launch guerrilla attacks against the invaders -- but how long they can sustain the fight in the face of the enemy's superior numbers and firepower remains in question.


To be specific, this is the remake of the movie with the same name that originally starred Patrick Swayze, Charlie Sheen, Jennifer Gray.

Considering that the original fits the timeline (pre-2000 movie) better, I'm guessing the original is the more likely answer.

@Catija But the plot of the movie is different. The trailer described fits the remake more than the original. So I'm guessing he/she just got the year wrong
